# ahref page linking issue on subdomain

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a base URL followed by separate sections, for example the index is http://www.speced.co.uk and the camera section is http://www.cameras.specced.co.uk..... I have created a new php page named 'compare.php' within the cameras section of my website, I need to link to this page from the http://www.cameras.specced.co.uk (index.php) page.

As I normally would with any other website, I have created the new php page (compare.php) and placed it next to the index.php page for the cameras.specced subdomain, I have linked to the (compare.php) from the (index.php) page using ahref:

```
<a href="compare.php">
compare
</a>
```

Strangely enough, this does not work and throws a 'File not found (404 error)' I don't have a clue why since I am very used to linking pages and I have done nothing different here.... the only real difference is that I am linking to a page within a subdomain, please see the file tree below:

1. ---- index.php 'specced.co.uk' (This is the first site page where you can chose to view the cameras, phones, etc sections )

Within the root folder there is a folder named 'cameras', this is for the sub domain 'cameras.specced.co.uk'

2. -- index.php 'cameras.specced.co.uk' this is the index page for the cameras.specced.co.uk sub domain, I am trying to link from here to another php page named 'compare.php'
3. -- compare.php, I am trying to link to this page from index.php I can not do this even though both files are right next to each other.

To confirm - I am trying to link from 2. to 3. both of these are within the 'cameras' folder which is the cameras.specced.co.uk sub domain.

I have created a htaccess file to hide the '.php' endings in the URL bar, this should not be affecting anything though, I have even removed this file all together and I cannot get these paged to link.

Please visit the domain 'specced.co.uk' then click cameras.... on the cameras page there is a small link 'compare' there should then take you to the compare.php page.... but it does not. I can make live edits to the site based off any suggestions received, I really need to get this solved and have spent a good few hours looking at this however just can't find anything wrong.

I appreciate any help.

htaccess rules :

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Could you add your .htaccess rules, the problem may lay there. Simple test, remove the rules and visit http://cameras.specced.co.uk/cameras/compare.php

Comment: I have just removed all the rules, and the problem continues, I will add the rules to the post above now. Thanks

Comment: Is the content in the `compare.php` file? I ask because if I remove the `cameras` part of the URL I get a file http://cameras.specced.co.uk/compare.php

Comment: @Msmit1993 Yes compare.php is empty, you was correct, removing the htaccess file did work, it must have been causing the issue, one other thing,  do you know why I cannot view cameras.specced.co.uk with the 'www.' on the front ?  Can you not use the www. wish subdomains ?

Comment: No this is not possible and not used often. However you could use a workaround for it. But I will depend on your hostingsprovider, if you host your own server or VPS try the vhost workaround https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404754/use-www-prefix-with-subdomain

Comment: @Msmit1993 Thankyou very much for your help I really appreciate it, If you write a short answer I will thumbs up, accept it.

Comment: Thanks again, Bradley